# Using default(DateTime)?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, default

Here's the snippet of my code.

```
var sc = dc.Schedules.FirstOrDefault(s => s.scheduleID == id);
schedule = new ScheduleModel
{
    ScheduleId = sc.scheduleID,
    Name = sc.scheduleName,
    StartDate = sc.startDate.HasValue ? sc.startDate.Value : default(DateTime),
    EndDate = sc.endDate.HasValue ? sc.endDate.Value : default(DateTime),
    StatusId = sc.statusID.HasValue ? sc.statusID.Value : default(int),
    //other properties
};
```

The original code didn't check `sc.startDate.HasValue`, and Resharper complained about `Possible System.InvalidOperationException` warning.

Then I added these conditions so that Resharper didn't complain anymore. But I was also wondering if it's right to use `default(DateTime) & defualt(int)` here. Would SQL Server accept its default `DateTime` value? Or should I perhaps use `DateTime.Now` instead?

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't resharper complain about a nullreference exception as sc isn't checked before it's used? PS SQL Server won't like default(DateTime) it's minimum value is circa 1753.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value of `DateTime` is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` whereas for [SQL Server the DateTime](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) field range is `January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999`, so its better if you use `NULL` instead of default value, as you **will not be able to store** the .Net framework default value for date in SQL Server.

For your class `ScheduleModel`, I would keep `StartDate` and `EndDate` as `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>`

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I'd like to know. So do you think if it's safe to ignore Resharper's warning?

Comment: Yeah, that's something I need to check out as well. Make StartDate and EndDate nullable perhaps is more preferred.

Comment: @woodykiddy, I am not sure why resharper is complaining about it, but this particular case I guess you can ignore it